# Отслеживание изменения атрибутов класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача отслеживать изменения атрибутов класса, что бы обновлять БД. Мне интересно, возможно ли такое реализовать? На данный момент есть такой код:

```py
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    if self.db_connection and not key.startswith('_'):
        self.write_to_table_attr(key, value)

    self.__dict__[key] = value
```

Но проблема в том, что если у меня один из атрибутов - класс, то при изменении его атрибута не будет использоваться **setattr** родителя, а значит обновление не запишется в БД.

Comment: Я вижу такие варианты: **1)** Сделайте аналогичный метод для того вашего класса, чьи изменения атрибутов вы хотите отслеживать. **2)** или базовый класс с перекрытым `__setattr__`, умеющим работать с базой данных, от этого класса будут наследованы все классы, чьи атрибуты будут записываться в базу **3)** или сделать метод-коллбек, который будет вызываться вложенными объектами, когда у них вызывается `__setattr__` (но тогда уж лучше сделать через базовый класс) **4)** использовать ORM библиотеку для работы с базой, мне, например понравилась `peewee`

Comment: @gil9red первые три варианта мне не очень подходят, так как к примеру будет проблема с dict. Если он один из атрибутов, то при его изменении код об этом не узнает, а создавать отдельные классы для этого не хочу, так как тогда мне нужно будет помнить, что вместо dict() нужно будет писать myDict() и т.д. На счёт 4 варианта, я никогда ещё не работал с ORM. Мне интересно, будет ли он автоматически создавать новый столбец с новым атрибутом и обновлять его при любых изменениях атрибутов?

Comment: В вашем примере нет ничего про словари, кроме `self.__dict__`, кст, в том месте можно было вызывать метод предка `super().__setattr__(key, value)`, но если хотите чтобы было отслеживание, то придется везде использовать тот код (варианты от 1 до 3), а насчет ORM... тут придется указать какие поля будут и с ними будет работа

Comment: dict же вроде класс, только встроенный, нет? А можно будет динамично добавлять поля, с которыми ведётся работа, как раз таки что бы при добавлении  атрибута с ними работать?

Comment: Угу, но он работает через метод `__setitem__`. Просто, вы используете `__setattr__`, а у него использование не через оператор квадратных скобок, а через имена атрибутов, типа `foo.abc = 123` и в key="abc", value=123. Если второй вопрос про ORM, то думаю, что можно, но придется использовать костыли, например, не думаю, что ORM сама заметит изменение значения того же словаря, ссылка ведь будет такая же. С другой стороны, вы можете сделать таблицу с полями Id, Key и Value, и через нее работать с ORM

Comment: Если с ORM будут костыли, то может такой такой вариант будет нормальным?: 1. Создаём декоратор, который после вызова функции обращается к БД; 2. Когда появляется новый атрибут - класс у родителя, то все его функции setitem, setattribute... обернуть в этот декоратор. Может тогда сработает? Но не знаю насколько такой вариант правильный.

Comment: Хм, нет, такой вариант всё же не сработает, так как нельзя изменять функцию встроенных классов.